# Ensuring Variable Accessibility in Asynchronous Method Chains

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

In the following code snippet:

```
void method1(String variable1) {
    String variable2 = "something";
    String variable3 = getValue3();

    service.asyncMethod1().thenAcceptAsync(result -> {
        service.asyncMethod2(variable1, variable2, variable3).thenAcceptAsync(result2 -> {
            log.info("success!");
        });
    }); 
}
```

How can I ensure that the variables variable1, variable2, and variable3 are correctly accessible when asyncMethod2 is called?
Considering that method1 might finish execution before asyncMethod1, how can I ensure that these variables are available when asyncMethod2 is called within thenAcceptAsync for the result of asyncMethod1?

EDIT: Async methods return CompletableFuture<>, method getValue3() is a plain synchronous method

Comment: You don't need to do anything, because Java copies those variables for use in the lambda exactly to avoid such lifetime dependencies. In other words, your question is based on a false premise that there is (or could be) a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The local *variables*, and parameter(s), are NOT accessed at the time the lambda body runs.**

When your code evaluates a lambda-expression, it returns a closure *object* which contains a copy of the *value* of each referenced local variable or method or constructor or exception parameter (all of which work like local variables, and in particular are implemented as stack slots); when you subsequently invoke the 'functional' method of that closure object -- i.e. 'run' the lambda -- it (as applicable) executes or evaluates the lambda body using those copied values, which exist as long as the closure object does, even if the original local(s) and/or parameter(s) have been deallocated because the code blocks declaring/allocating them have completed.

Since an update to the copy in the closure wouldn't affect the original and an update to the original wouldn't affect the copy, Java prohibits *any* update. See the 11th paragraph in [JLS 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) "Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in a lambda expression must either be final or effectively final ....". If it is declared final the language prevents you from re-assigning it; if it is effectively final you didn't attempt to re-assign it. If you do re-assign it, you can't use it in a lambda-body.

This is similar to the way an inner class works -- if in instance context it has a *reference* to the outer-class object for that context, thus it can write to fields of that object and see writes done elsewhere, but if local or anonymous it has (only) copies of any local variable(s) or parameter(s) used, which may go out of existence while the inner-class object survives. In early versions of Java, such referenced locals had to be declared final; Java 8 relaxed this to 'effectively final' where simply not re-assigning it is enough.